# Know the amount of objects Serializable from file

Tags: java, object, serializable

I am reading objects from a file using Serializable:

```
    public ArrayList<Object> deserialzePerson(String filename) {
    Object obj = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois;
    try {
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            obj = (Object) ois.readObject();
            ObjectArray.add(obj);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return ObjectArray;
}
```

However, I do not know the amount of objects in the file and use the number "100" in the for-loop. If there are less than 100, the exception will kick in and everything goes as expected. Nevertheless, I find this solution poor because it depends on catching errors. Is there a way to set the limit of the for-loop for the amount of objects in the file?

For instance, when reading from a .txt file I used `.hasNext();` is there something like this for objects?

Comment: When you serializing the persons array you should write its size before the content, and read it when when you deserializing it.

Comment: @chaim I do not understand what you mean, please elaborate! I want to set a limit in the for-loop for the amount of objects in the file. How will I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void serializePerson(String filename, List<Person> persons) {
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
         ObjectOutputStream ous = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)) {

        ous.writeInt(persons.size());
        for (Person person : persons) {
            ous.writeObject(person);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

public List<Person> deserializePerson(String filename) {
    List<Person> result = new ArrayList<>();
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
         ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis)) {
        int size = ois.readInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            Person person = (Person) ois.readObject();
            result.add(person);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Makes my code somewhat longer, but exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Actually, some list implementations, like ArrayList, are serializable themself, so you can just out.writeObject(persons) and persons = (List<Person>)in.readObject()

Answer (score 1):

**However, I do not know the amount of objects in the file and use the number "100" in the for-loop**
The best alternate to the for-loop for reading the objects would be

```
try {
    int currentCounter = 0; 
    ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
    for (Object obj = null; (obj = ois.readObject()) != null ; currentCounter++) 
    {
        ObjectArray.add(obj);
        // currentCounter is the way out in this case, but I can give more explanations
    }
} catch (Exception e) 
 {
    if( e instanceof EOFException )
    {
        System.err.println( e.getClass() + "=" + e.getMessage() );
    }
    else
    {
        System.err.println( "UNKNOWN INSTANCE: " + e.getClass() + "=" + e.getMessage() );
    }
 }
```

Wrapped around with a bunch of event-listener mechanism, you could even do better. The problem is whether you want a pre or post knowledge about the count of number of objects before you plan the file read

Answer (score 1):

You can write the size or a much simpler solution is to write the List is which also an object.

```
public static void save(String filename, Object o) {
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
         ObjectOutputStream ous = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)) {
        ous.writeObject(o);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public static <T> T load(String filename) {
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
         ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis)) {
        return (T) ois.readObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

e.g.

```
List<Person> people = load("people.dat");
people.add(new Person());
save("people.dat", people);
```

This allows you to write an object or any type with less code.

Answer (score 0):

Short version -  you cannot.   Long version,  you can if you write amount of objects as int ( or long ) into stream at first position - and then read it first.

You can also rely on EOFException which will be thrown if there are no objects anymore

Comment: Pretty sure - even looked into javadoc :)  But java serialsation is not a good tool to store objects anyway. It is not good for anything at all

Comment: What would you recommend using?

Comment: Something like GSON / XStream  - there is a lot of serialisation libraries around